# Root item type in a plist file?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, plist

How do I check a plist's root item is array or dictionary?
Thanks for helping

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using following way you can detect root element of dictionary is an array or not through objective-C

```
NSString *thePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"YourCustom" ofType:@"plist"];
NSURL *theUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:thePath];

id messagesInfo = [[NSDictionary dictionary] initWithContentsOfURL:theUrl];
if([messagesInfo isKindOfClass:NSDictionary]){
    NSLog(@"DictionaryFound");
}
else{
  NSLog(@"Array Found");
}
```

Comment: Ideally the code should also check if `messagesInfo` is `nil` just in case the URL doesn't refer to a valid plist file (or a non-existent file).